# Android Tablet + Master Detail view + Xamarin: menu disappears only on very right side click insead of anywhere on dimmed area

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, tablet, master-detail

There is a Xamarin.Forms App, which has Master (=menu) / Detail views implemented. If you click on hamburger menu, menu (=Master) appears, background (=current Detail view) is dimmed. If you click outside the menu, it disappears automatically.

It works fine on Android phone + iOS phone + iOS tablet, but on Android tablet, the opened menu does not disappear if you click outside of the menu (so you click on the dimmed area), but only on the very right side of the screen.

[[**See screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyoIv.png)]: you have to click on the yellow area to close the menu, while on android phone or ios phone/tablet, it works fine, you can click anywhere on the dimmed area, menu will close.

I have not found any similar issue, while it's happening, and I am out of clue what could cause it.
Any hint, help, where to start?

Thanks

Comment: [MasterDetailPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage?view=xamarin-forms) is obsolete as of version 5.0.0. Please use [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but we use MVVMCross, which does NOT support 5.0.0 :(
Also, we do not use directly MasterDetailPage, we use MVVMCross MvxMasterDetailPage, which most likely internally use MasterDetailPage

Comment: UPDATE: I just checked, latest MVVMCross8 finally supports Xamarin5. However, not sure if its MvxMasterDetailPage uses FlyoutPage or still the MasterDetailPage

Comment: UPDATE2: I just checked MVVMCross8 changes, and one is that it uses FlyoutPage instead of MasterDetailPage!